# FSL installation in Ubuntu FAILED message

Tags: installation

I am a traditional Windows user and therefore you have to excuse me for my lack of experience with other OS. I installed Ubuntu in order to install FSL in my computer (seems the Windows installation failed so I tried this). However, the download goes right, but at the end it says "[FAILED] Unable to unpack FSL".
How can I solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should ask this in [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, this is not a programming question. If it can still be moved to AskUbuntu (or SuperUser) it may be better appreciated.*

In Ubuntu the easy way to install software is through the package manager. This is by far the least amount of work and installs binary packages in default locations (FSL is in the path straight away), plus it takes care of all the dependencies!

FSL is in the NeuroDebian repository, and if you add this to one of your 'software sources' then you can install it via Ubuntu's package manager, APT:

1. go to https://neuro.debian.net and find out how to add the right repository, e.g.

   `$ wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/focal.de-fzj.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list`
   `$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9`
2. update the list of packages APT can find:

   `$ sudo apt update`
3. install the fsl packages you want, e.g.

   `$ sudo apt install fsl-5.0 fsl-harvard-oxford-cortical-lateralized-atlas`